# How to handle more than one Firebase in one swiftui app?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I tried to create a swiftui app with flutter framework (have Firebase dependency in it) implemented in it. It went well up until I needed to add Firebase Auth into the swiftui app, I have two problems:

1. Error when building the app: 'redefinition of module Firebase' -> It solved by removing the package dependency of Firebase on the swiftui. I install the framework using CocoaPod method and add the Firebase SDK through Swift Package Manager (I do not know if this is the source of error or not) If not, how do you handle if the framework and the app do not share the same version of Firebase?
2. Error when running the app: A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists -> many suggest placing the initialization on the very root of the app, or removing the initialize in the flutter framework, is there any way around?

Thanks in advance